# Add the language in the url / fr /, / en /, etc internationalization spring boot mvc

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, multilingual

I followed this tutorial

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization

I managed to get it to work: when I put the following url [www.example.com/?lang=en](http://www.example.com/?lang=en) I have the English version that is displayed.

However, I want to "convert" it so that the lang is directly in the example url [www.example.com/en/](http://www.example.com/en/) or [www.example.com/fr/](http://www.example.com/fr/).

So i have this

```
@Configuration
public class Locale implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        return slr;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor localeInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        localeInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return localeInterceptor;
    }

    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
    }
}
```

I was thinking of using a filter, which will redirect to [www.example.com/en/](http://www.example.com/en/) or / fr / and if it can't find the language, configure the controller that if / {language} is null then it ignores it.

However, I do not know if my approach is good and especially I do not know how to retrieve the information of the language in the filter.

Could you help me ?

thank you

Comment: you using locale right?

Comment: Yes quite. If the user has put "accept English" in his browser, the site translates into English, "accept French" it appears in French, if I add ?Lang=en in it is in English ?Lang=fr it is displayed in French. But I want example.com/fr/ example.com/en/ and all translation messages are in messages_LANG.properties

Comment: sorry, I meant: private static final ResourceBundle messages = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages", locale);